# prevent duplicate row in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, duplicates, row, cql

I have a CF, its PK is an UUID, I also have a column like regNum, it's a natural key. I do have an index on regNum.

Currently, whenever I try to insert a new record, I do a query on regNum to make sure there is no duplicate before generating an UUID for insertion.

However, I found out I do have duplicate regNum in this CF. Any idea how to prevent this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you set regNum as your key instead of the UUID. That will solve your problem